# Azure Speech API language

Tags: azure, speech-to-text, azure-cognitive-services, azure-speech

I have implemented a chat on a web page, with the possibility to use Speech to text, using Azure Speech API. It works fine but I don't understand where I can set the language understood by the API.
I want it to understand french, but when I talk in french, it transcripts in english words with familiar sound.
How / Where I can I set the language ?
I precise that I'm not the one who set up the service on Azure dashboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a `locale` parameter that you can use optionally like the following [example](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/blob/master/src/CognitiveServices/SpeechRecognition.ts#L16):

```
export interface ICognitiveServicesSpeechRecognizerProperties {
    locale?: string,
    subscriptionKey?: string,
    fetchCallback?: (authFetchEventId: string) => Promise<string>,
    fetchOnExpiryCallback?: (authFetchEventId: string) => Promise<string>
}
```

If you don't provide a value the following [example](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/blob/master/src/CognitiveServices/SpeechRecognition.ts#L41) is used:

```
const locale = properties.locale || 'en-US';
```

You can find the possible values for those parameters [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/supported-languages)

Answer (score 0):

The new [SpeechSDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/Speech-Service/) supports recognition in different languages, please check samples [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-speech-sdk/blob/master/samples/csharp/sharedcontent/console/speech_recognition_samples.cs#L58).

Thanks,