# Botframework emulator speech language

Tags: azure, speech-to-text, azure-cognitive-services, azure-speech

I want to use the speech to text in Botframework Emulator.
I put "fr-FR" in 'locale' field, just after my microsft app id & password.
The speech to text works great but does not understand french. Only english.
What should I do to make it understand french ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Azure Speech API language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51300534/azure-speech-api-language)

Comment: Thanks but it was me, I'm asking something different.